# D3 scaleBand with variable band widths

Tags: javascript, d3.js, visualization

## Context

I'm making a graph of some categorised data. Each category is of equal conceptual weight, so I'd like to dedicate the same amount of width to each of the categories. This hand drawn graph demonstrates it:

[image: A hand drawn version of the graph described]

I'd also like the verticals to run similarly. I've got that much working in the graph shown below (and in the code snippet):

[image: The output of the code attached]

```js
function draw_graph(columnData) {
  const colTitles = [
    "Tectonics",
    "Technology",
    "Team Skills",
    "Design ⚠",
    "Connecting with country ⚠",
    "Regenerative ⚠",
    "BIM ⚠",
    "QA ⚠",
    "Making ⚠",
    "Interiors ⚠",
    "Project Leadership ⚠",
  ];

  // Chart dimensions
  const margin = { top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40 };
  const width = 1200 - margin.left - margin.right;
  const height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  // Create SVG element
  const svg = d3
    .select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left},${margin.top})`);

  // Define the scales
  const xScale = d3
    .scaleBand()
    .range([margin.left, width - margin.right])
    .domain(colTitles);

  const yScale = d3
    .scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(columnData, (d) => d.level) + 1])
    .nice()
    .range([height - margin.bottom, margin.top]);

  // Create a color scale based on the scores
  const colorScale = d3
    .scaleOrdinal()
    .domain(["x", "o", "p", "a", " "])
    .range(["green", "#12eb12", "#a5e3a5", "yellow", "#ffffff00"]);
  const perimeter_colour = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)";

  const yAxis = svg
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left},0)`)
    .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale).ticks(5, ""))
    .call((g) => g.select(".domain").remove())
    .call((g) =>
      g
        .selectAll(".tick line")
        .clone()
        .attr("x2", width)
        .attr("stroke-opacity", 0.1)
    )
    .call((g) =>
      g
        .select(".tick:last-of-type text")
        .clone()
        .attr("x", 4)
        .attr("text-anchor", "start")
        .attr("font-weight", "bold")
        .text("Skill level")
    );
  // Create x-axis
  const xAxis = svg
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", `translate(0,${height - margin.bottom})`)
    .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale).ticks(width / 80))
    .call((g) => g.select(".domain").remove())
    .call((g) =>
      g
        .selectAll(".tick line")
        .clone()
        .attr("y2", -height)
        .attr("stroke-opacity", 0.1)
    )
    .call((g) =>
      g
        .append("text")
        .attr("x", width - 4)
        .attr("y", -4)
        .attr("font-weight", "bold")
        .attr("text-anchor", "end")
        .attr("fill", "currentColor")
        .text("Competency Domain")
    );

  // Create stacked rectangles
  const rects = svg
    .selectAll("rect")
    .data(columnData)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .selectAll("rect")
    .data((d) =>
      d.scores.map((score, index) => ({
        tab: d.tab,
        level: d.level,
        index,
      }))
    )
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("x", (d) => xScale(d.tab))
    .attr("y", (d) => {
      // Calculate the y position based on the number of values in the scores list
      const rectCount = columnData.find(
        (item) => item.tab === d.tab && item.level === d.level
      ).scores.length;
      const y = yScale(d.level + 1 / rectCount + (1 / rectCount) * d.index);
      // console.log({ y, d, rectCount });
      return y;
    })
    .attr("width", xScale.bandwidth())
    .attr("height", (d) => {
      // Calculate the height based on the number of values in the scores list
      const rectCount = columnData.find(
        (item) => item.tab === d.tab && item.level === d.level
      ).scores.length;
      return (yScale(1) - yScale(2)) / rectCount;
    })
    //   .attr("data-help", (d) => JSON.stringify(d))
    .attr("stroke", perimeter_colour)
    .attr("fill", (d) =>
      colorScale(
        columnData.find((item) => item.tab === d.tab && item.level === d.level)
          .scores[d.index]
      )
    );

  // Create a legend to show the meaning of the colors
  const legend = svg
    .append("g")
    .attr(
      "transform",
      `translate(${width - margin.right - 120},${margin.top})`
    );

  // Background rectangle behind the legend
  legend
    .append("rect")
    .attr("x", -10)
    .attr("y", -30)
    .attr("width", 130)
    .attr("height", 115)
    .attr("rx", 10)
    .attr("fill", "hwb(0deg 100% 0% / 65%)")
    .attr("stroke", "hwb(0deg 100% 0% / 80%)");

  // Add a title for the legend
  legend
    .append("text")
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", -10)
    .attr("font-weight", "bold")
    .text("Score Legend");

  // Add a group for each color and score
  const legendGroups = legend
    .selectAll("g")
    .data(colorScale.domain())
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", (d, i) => `translate(0,${i * 20})`);

  // Add a colored rectangle for each color and score
  legendGroups
    .append("rect")
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", 0)
    .attr("width", 15)
    .attr("height", 15)
    .attr("fill", (d) => colorScale(d));

  // Add a text label for each color and score
  legendGroups
    .append("text")
    .attr("x", 20)
    .attr("y", 12)
    .text((d) => d);

  // Create a tooltip to show the details of each bar on mouseover
  const tooltip = d3
    .select("body")
    .append("div")
    .attr("class", "tooltip")
    .style("position", "absolute")
    .style("visibility", "hidden")
    .style("background-color", "white")
    .style("border", "solid")
    .style("border-width", "1px")
    .style("border-radius", "5px")
    .style("padding", "10px");

  // Add mouseover and mouseout events to the rects
  rects
    .on("mouseover", (event, d) => {
      // Show the tooltip with the details of the bar
      tooltip
        .style("visibility", "visible")
        .html(
          `Tab: ${d.tab}<br>Level: ${d.level}<br>Score: ${
            columnData.find(
              (item) => item.tab === d.tab && item.level === d.level
            ).scores[d.index]
          }`
        );
      // Highlight the bar with a darker stroke
      d3.select(event.currentTarget).attr("stroke", "black");
    })
    .on("mousemove", (event) => {
      // Move the tooltip with the mouse cursor
      tooltip
        .style("top", event.pageY + 10 + "px")
        .style("left", event.pageX + 10 + "px");
    })
    .on("mouseout", (event, d) => {
      // Hide the tooltip
      tooltip.style("visibility", "hidden");
      // Restore the original stroke color of the bar
      d3.select(event.currentTarget).attr("stroke", perimeter_colour);
    });
}

const columnData = [
  { tab: "Tectonics", level: 0, scores: ["x"] },
  { tab: "Tectonics", level: 1, scores: ["x", "o", "p", "a"] },
  { tab: "Tectonics", level: 2, scores: ["x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x"] },
  { tab: "Tectonics", level: 3, scores: ["x", "x", "o", "p", " "] },
  { tab: "Tectonics", level: 4, scores: ["x", "x", "a", " ", " ", " "] },
  {
    tab: "Tectonics",
    level: 5,
    scores: ["x", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
  },
  { tab: "Technology", level: 0, scores: ["x"] },
  { tab: "Technology", level: 1, scores: ["x", "x", "o", "p"] },
  { tab: "Technology", level: 2, scores: ["x", "x", "x", "x", "o", "p"] },
  { tab: "Technology", level: 3, scores: ["x", "x", "x", "p", "a"] },
  { tab: "Technology", level: 4, scores: ["x", "o", "p", "a", " ", " "] },
  { tab: "Technology", level: 5, scores: ["x", "o", " ", " ", " ", " "] },
  { tab: "Team Skills", level: 0, scores: ["x"] },
  { tab: "Team Skills", level: 1, scores: ["x", "x", "x", "o", "p"] },
  { tab: "Team Skills", level: 2, scores: ["x", "a", "p", "o"] },
  { tab: "Team Skills", level: 3, scores: ["p", "x", "x", "o", "p"] },
  {
    tab: "Team Skills",
    level: 4,
    scores: ["x", "o", "p", "a", " ", " "],
  },
  { tab: "Team Skills", level: 5, scores: [" ", " ", " "] },
  { tab: "Design ⚠", level: 0, scores: ["x"] },
  { tab: "Design ⚠", level: 1, scores: ["x", "x", "o", "p"] },
  { tab: "Design ⚠", level: 2, scores: ["x", "x", "x", "x", "o", "p"] },
  { tab: "Design ⚠", level: 3, scores: ["x", "x", "x", "p", "a"] },
  { tab: "Design ⚠", level: 4, scores: ["x", "o", "p", "a", " ", " "] },
  { tab: "Design ⚠", level: 5, scores: ["x", "o", "p", " ", " ", " "] },
  { tab: "Connecting with country ⚠", level: 0, scores: ["x"] },
  {
    tab: "Connecting with country ⚠",
    level: 1,
    scores: ["x", "x"],
  },
  {
    tab: "Connecting with country ⚠",
    level: 2,
    scores: ["x", "x", "x", "x", "o", "p"],
  },
  {
    tab: "Connecting with country ⚠",
    level: 3,
    scores: ["x", "x", "x", "p", "a"],
  },
  {
    tab: "Connecting with country ⚠",
    level: 4,
    scores: ["x", "o", "p", "a", " ", " "],
  },
  {
    tab: "Connecting with country ⚠",
    level: 5,
    scores: ["p", " "],
  },
  { tab: "Regenerative ⚠", level: 0, scores: ["x"] },
  { tab: "Regenerative ⚠", level: 1, scores: ["p", "x", "o"] },
  {
    tab: "Regenerative ⚠",
    level: 2,
    scores: ["x", "x", "x", "x", "o", "p"],
  },
  { tab: "Regenerative ⚠", level: 3, scores: ["a", "x", "x", "p", "a"] },
  {
    tab: "Regenerative ⚠",
    level: 4,
    scores: ["x", "o", "p", "a", " ", " "],
  },
  {
    tab: "Regenerative ⚠",
    level: 5,
    scores: ["x", "o", "p", " ", " ", " "],
  },
  { tab: "BIM ⚠", level: 0, scores: ["x"] },
  { tab: "BIM ⚠", level: 1, scores: ["x", "x", "o", "p"] },
  { tab: "BIM ⚠", level: 2, scores: ["x", "x", "x", "o", "p"] },
  { tab: "BIM ⚠", level: 3, scores: ["x", "o", "x", "p", "a"] },
  { tab: "BIM ⚠", level: 4, scores: ["x", "o", "p", "a", " ", " "] },
  { tab: "BIM ⚠", level: 5, scores: ["x", "o", "p", " ", " ", " "] },
  { tab: "QA ⚠", level: 0, scores: ["x"] },
  { tab: "QA ⚠", level: 1, scores: ["x", "x", "o", "p"] },
  { tab: "QA ⚠", level: 2, scores: ["x", "p"] },
  { tab: "QA ⚠", level: 3, scores: ["x", "x", "p", "x"] },
  { tab: "QA ⚠", level: 4, scores: ["p", "o", "a", " ", " "] },
  { tab: "QA ⚠", level: 5, scores: [" ", " ", " "] },
  { tab: "Making ⚠", level: 0, scores: ["x"] },
  { tab: "Making ⚠", level: 1, scores: ["x", "x", "o", "p"] },
  { tab: "Making ⚠", level: 2, scores: ["x", "x", "x", "x", "o", "p"] },
  { tab: "Making ⚠", level: 3, scores: ["p", "p", "p", "a"] },
  { tab: "Making ⚠", level: 4, scores: ["x", "o", "p", "a", " ", " "] },
  { tab: "Making ⚠", level: 5, scores: ["x", "o", "p", " ", " ", " "] },
  { tab: "Interiors ⚠", level: 0, scores: ["x"] },
  { tab: "Interiors ⚠", level: 1, scores: ["x", "x", "o", "p"] },
  { tab: "Interiors ⚠", level: 2, scores: ["x", "x", "o", "p"] },
  { tab: "Interiors ⚠", level: 3, scores: ["x", "x", "x", "p", "a"] },
  { tab: "Interiors ⚠", level: 4, scores: ["o", "p", "a", " "] },
  { tab: "Interiors ⚠", level: 5, scores: ["o", "p", " "] },
  { tab: "Project Leadership ⚠", level: 0, scores: ["x"] },
  { tab: "Project Leadership ⚠", level: 1, scores: ["x", "x", "o", "p"] },
  {
    tab: "Project Leadership ⚠",
    level: 2,
    scores: ["x", "x", "x", "o", "p"],
  },
  {
    tab: "Project Leadership ⚠",
    level: 3,
    scores: ["x", "x", "x", "p", "a"],
  },
  {
    tab: "Project Leadership ⚠",
    level: 4,
    scores: ["o", "p", "a", " ", " "],
  },
  { tab: "Project Leadership ⚠", level: 5, scores: ["o", "p", " "] },
];
draw_graph(columnData);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

## Question

Is there a concept in D3 that is a combination of a linear scale and a band scale? I'd like to be able to split a column, e.g. Team, into three.

I could try something like `xScale('Team') + (xScale.bandwidth()/3)` etc. but if there's a more elegant solution I'd prefer it.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that my throw away comment at the end of the question actually worked out.

[image]

The data now has has a segment key:

```
{
    "tab": "Tectonics",
    "segment": 0,
    "level": 3,
    "scores": ["p", " ", " ", "x", " ", " "]
  },
```

and the `x` and `width` use the `scaleBand` function to get the left hand side of the band, and then the `xScale.bandwidth()` function to get the width of the band. The rest is some maths and jiggling until it's right.

```
.attr("x", (d) => {
    const num_bands = new Set(
        columnData
        .filter((item) => item.tab === d.tab)
        .map((x) => x.segment)
    ).size;
    return xScale(d.tab) + (xScale.bandwidth() / num_bands) * d.segment;
    })
    ...
.attr("width", (d) => {
    const num_bands = new Set(
        columnData
        .filter((item) => item.tab === d.tab)
        .map((x) => x.segment)
    ).size;
    return xScale.bandwidth() / num_bands;
    })
```

It feels quite inefficient because each rectangle filters the whole dataset at least three times, but it's still usably fast. If anyone has any suggestions about alternative approaches I'd love to hear.